# How to get username of a person who is logged in,from database mysql in node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, authentication

I have made a login system where i am logging in using mobile number and password.Before my code was showing welcome back 03**** ** because i had used `request.session.number`. I have changed the code so that i can get first name from the database whether employer or helper login.But it is not working.It is showing `welcome back, undefined`. I am unable to get the name from database.Can anyone tell me how to get it or where i am wrong. I will be thankful if anyone can help me in this regard.

```
app.post('/auth', function(request, response) {
    var number = request.body.number;
    var password = request.body.pwd;

     if (number && password) {
    var sql = `SELECT fyp_helpers.Mobile_number AS number,fyp_helpers.Password AS  Password FROM fyp_helpers  WHERE Mobile_number = ? UNION SELECT 
            fyp_employers.Employer_Contact AS number , fyp_employers.Employer_Password AS Employer_Password FROM fyp_employers 
        WHERE Employer_Contact = ?`;
    connection.query(sql, [number, number], function (error, results, fields) {
        if (results.length > 0) {
            var hashedPassword = results[0].Password;
            bcrypt.compare(password, hashedPassword, function (cryptErr, cryptResult) {
                if (cryptResult) {
                    request.session.loggedin = true;
                    request.session.number = number;
                  var name= connection.query(`select fyp_helpers.First_Name As name FROM fyp_helpers UNION select fyp_employers.Employer_Fname As name FROM fyp_employers`,[name,name],function(error, results, fields)
                   {
                    if(!err) 
                        console.log(name);
                    else
                        console.log(error);
                   })
                    response.redirect('/home');
                } else {
                    response.send('Incorrect Password!');
                    console.log(cryptErr);
                }
                response.end();
            });
        } else {
            response.send('User not registered');
        }
    });
}
        else {
        response.send('Please enter Username and Password!');
        response.end();
    }

});
app.get('/home', function(request, response) {
    if (request.session.loggedin) {
        response.send('Welcome back, ' + request.session.name + '!');
    } else {
        response.send('Please login to view this page!');
    }
    response.end();
});
app.listen(3000);
```

Everything is working fine but the only problem is it is not getting name.

**Edit**

```
 var name= connection.query(`select fyp_helpers.First_Name As name FROM fyp_helpers UNION select fyp_employers.Employer_Fname As name FROM fyp_employers`,[name,name],function(error, results, fields)
                   {
                    if(!error) {
                        request.session.name = name;
                        console.log(name);
                    }
                    else
                        console.log(error);
                   })
```

I have declared name to session but it is still not working.Do i place it on wrong position or my query is not right to select the name?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `name` in `request.session.name`. Variable `name` is fetched but not used.

Comment: i have added it in the ```\home``` route where else to place it?

Comment: After fetching `name` in `\auth` you are not assigning it to `request.session`. Just like you did for `request.session.number = number`, likewise you must also assign `request.session.name = name` after fetching the name.

Comment: i have updated the part above. It still not getting. Can you please check whether i placed it in right place or is there something wrong with my query?

Comment: Since the query execution is asynchronous, you have to redirect once the execution is complete. In order to do that you have to place `response.redirect('/home');` inside `name` `connection.query` callback. In you current implementation it's getting redirect before the complete execution of query.

Comment: Also the `results` must be used to obtain the fetched name. `https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#performing-queries`